# Extending JavaScript Classes for use on Canvas

Tags: javascript, class, extend, createjs

I am working on a project to help me gain a better understanding of JavaScript and building applications with it.  I am currently making a game utilizing createjs.  I'd like to extend the Shape "class" by adding some additional methods to it but can't seem to get my head around the issue.

I am not getting any runtime errors by this approach, however I think it's failing silently at a particular point.

### My Subclass:

```
ShipGFX.prototype = new createjs.Shape();
    function ShipGFX()
    {
        createjs.Shape.apply( this );

        this.draw = function()
        {
            var g = this.graphics;

            g.clear();
            g.setStrokeStyle( 1 );
            g.beginStroke( createjs.Graphics.getRGB( 0x00ff00 ) );
            g.beginFill( createjs.Graphics.getRGB( 0x00ff00, 0.5 ) );
            g.moveTo( 0, 0 );
            g.lineTo( -5, -5 );
            g.lineTo( 10, 0 );
            g.lineTo( -5, 5 );
            g.lineTo( 0, 0 );
            g.endFill();
        }
    }
```

### Where it's used:

```
var shape = new ShipGFX();
shape.draw();
```

So the console logs no errors and I can even log via the draw command.  I think the issue is scope of this.graphics even though it doesn't fail there either.  Is it a matter of scope?  Is the this.graphics a reference to the prototype instance (if I understand that correctly).  I'd ideally like to use **[Class-js](https://github.com/rauschma/class-js/blob/master/Class.js)** as I have a better understanding of how it works but I can't even get this way to work.

Any input would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this was failing silently was because little did I realize that the draw function was preexisting in the createjs.Shape APIs.  Changing the name to "render" solved my issue.